# Is there anything like "maxQueryTime"? and if yes then How can I set mongo maxQueryTime?

Tags: mongodb

Facing degraded performance on mongo servers, so in order to debug it, we tried

```
db.currentOp({ "active" : true, "secs_running" : { "$gt" : 1 }})
```

to check the current operations taking more than 1 sec, and found that there were more than 2 queries running for more than 500 seconds. As of now we cant control the source which is querying. So what we did is killed those operations using.

```
db.killOp()
```

Now Is there a way I drop all those queries taking more than x seconds automatically, once they are done executing for x seconds with response?

Note:- cannot edit the queries, want it to be in mongod config file.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/cursor.maxTimeMS/

Comment: dude, have already gone through it, before posting this question, this is based on the cursor, means I have to manually add this with each and every query, I want it in the config, with maxConnectionLimit, and other config variables.

Comment: Doesn't look like it: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8499

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/parameters/#param.cursorTimeoutMillis at the mongod level so that it applies to all queries. The default is 10 minutes(!).

In the meantime, you could run a script to kill the queries automatically.

Formatted for readability:

```
while(true) { 
  var data = db.currentOp({ "active" : true, "secs_running" : { "$gt" : 1 }})["inprog"]; 

  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i ++) { 
    var operation = data[i]; 
    print("Killing " + operation.opid); db.killOp(operation.opid); 
  }

  sleep(500); 
}
```

Formatted for the shell:

```
while(true) { var data = db.currentOp({ "active" : true, "secs_running" : { "$gt" : 1 }})["inprog"]; for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i ++) { var operation = data[i]; print("Killing " + operation.opid); db.killOp(operation.opid); }  sleep(500); }
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the help, this is what I was looking for.